# How do I get the selected row data from a data grid view using SelectedRows?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a table that I am displaying in a data grid view control. The user selects a single row from the control and presses a button. I need to retrieve the cells from that row and store them as strings.

Exactly how do I get the data using the SelectedRow method? I've been working on this for several hours and I'm at the end of my rope. Here's an example of something I've tried:

```
DataGridViewCellCollection selRowData = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells;
```

If I try to access selRowData[x], the return value does not contain my data.

Comment: Answer [here][1] iterates through all cells to build a text string.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10525686

Answer (score 6):

You're close - you need to reference each `Cell` through its index and return its `Value` property:

```
string firstCellValue = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
string secondCellValue = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value;
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the data and the data is likely bound to an datasource, then might I suggest that you get the key from the selection, and then you can use that to access the data any way you like:

```
dataGridView.SelectedDataKey.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Item element of the dgv.

```
dgvFoo.Item(0, dgvFoo.CurrentRow.Index).Value
```

That would return the value of the first item. You could put that into a for loop to get them all.

Another option would be to use the SelectedRows collection on the object and iterate through each selected row (or just the one in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no datagridview Item property..@Jay Riggs solution is better...Following solution also works:

```
string firstCellValue = dataGridView1[0,dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
string secondCellValue = dataGridView1[0,dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString();
```

Here 0 is the first column and dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index is the current Row from where to get value.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a more suitable solution use the cell values of the row clicked:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.RowIndex > -1)
  {
    var val = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
  }
}
```