# Datagridview full row selection but get single cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is a full row select.
How would I grab the data from only a certain cell no matter what cell in the row was clicked on since it highlights the entire row.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the selected row data from a data grid view using SelectedRows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552497/how-do-i-get-the-selected-row-data-from-a-data-grid-view-using-selectedrows)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can do like this:

```cs
private void datagridview1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (datagridview1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
  {
    int selectedrowindex = datagridview1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
    DataGridViewRow selectedRow = datagridview1.Rows[selectedrowindex];  
    string cellValue = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["enter column name"].Value);           
  }
}
```

Comment: @pratap K , Does DataGridView1_SelectionChanged event will fire at the time of form load ? but it is happening in my case. Please help me resolve this. If needed more details I will post it as a question.

Comment: I wanted the opposite behavior and your posted helped me realize what I needed to do. SelectedCells.Count == 1 :)

Answer (score 25):

If you want to get the contents of selected cell; you need the index of row and cell.

```
int rowindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
int columnindex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex; 

dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 10):

I know, I'm a little late for the answer. But I would like to contribute.

```
DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value
```

This code is simple as piece of cake

Comment: Only 6 and a half years late!

Answer (score 8):

In the CellClick event you can write following code

```
string value =
      datagridviewID.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
```

Using the bove code you will get value of the cell you cliked. If you want to get value of paricular column in the clicked row, just replace  e.ColumnIndex with the column index you want

Comment: This is more better answer, just need to change `e.ColumnIndex` with specific string column name or index since question ansked for it.

Answer (score 5):

you can get the values of the cell also as the current selection is referenced under `CurrentRow`

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cell[indexorname].FormattedValue
```

Here you can use index or column name and get the value.

Answer (score 2):

`DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[n]`

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out, you can use .selectedindex to make it a little cleaner

```
string value = gridview.Rows[gridview.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string value = dataGridVeiw1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just Use:** `dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()`

```
        private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
        }
```

or

```
 // dataGrid1.Rows[yourRowIndex ].Cells[yourColumnIndex].Value.ToString()

 //Example1:yourRowIndex=dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index (from selectedRow );
 dataGrid1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString()

 //Example2:yourRowIndex=3,yourColumnIndex=2 (select by programmatically )
  dataGrid1.Rows[3].Cells[2].Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

this get me the text value of exact cell in data grid view

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = dataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[#].Value.ToString();
    }
```

you can see it in label and change # wih the index of the exact cell you want

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cell Click` as other methods mentioned will fire upon data binding, not useful if you want the selected value, then the form to close.

```
private void dgvProducts_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvProducts.SelectedCells.Count > 0) // Checking to see if any cell is selected
    {
        int mSelectedRowIndex = dgvProducts.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

        DataGridViewRow mSelectedRow = dgvProducts.Rows[mSelectedRowIndex];

        string mCatagoryName = Convert.ToString(mSelectedRow.Cells[1].Value);

        SomeOtherMethod(mProductName); // Passing the name to where ever you need it

        this.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who could not fire the click event, they may use following code

```
public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.dataGridView1.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get one cell value based on entire row selection:

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
           {
               TextBox1.Text = row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value.ToString();
           }
      }
else
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select item!");
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest code is `DataGridView1.SelectedCells(column_index).Value`

As an example, for the first selected cell:

```
DataGridView1.SelectedCells(0).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;

Answer (score 0):

for vb.net 2013 i use

```
DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Item(0).Cells(i).Value
```

where i is the cell number

Answer (score 0):

Assigns cell 1 of dgwProduct lines to ProductId.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(dgwProduct.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value);
    }
```

Here it puts all the cells in the row into the textbox.

```
private void dgwProduct_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var row=dgwProduct.CurrentRow;
        tbxProductName.Text =row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        tbxUnitPrice.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        tbxQuantityPerUnit.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        tbxStockUpdate.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
    }
```

In this way, we assign all the cells in the dataGridView to the textboxes.

Comment: You can also check here:                                                     
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void DataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridViewX3.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedrowindex = dataGridViewX3.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dataGridViewX3.Rows[selectedrowindex];
            string cellValue = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells[0].Value);
            Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when select a row get value of datagridview and show.