# C# dataGridView click change trackbar value

Tags: c#

I want some simple thing ,but I dont know how do this. When I click on dataGridView some row ,to one column I have some int value. I need to set value to trackbar. How I can do this?

This is the last code, what I tried

```
 trackBar1.Value = row.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString();c
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Fred when I click on row data, all data what I have ,writes into textboxes ,but I want that last priority data value show at trackbar

Comment: If you follow that link is shows you how to do that. Replace "you have to mention you cell  corresponding column name" with "priority" if that's the name of the cell you are interested in.  Check the value is numeric, convert it to an `int` ( `Convert.ToInt32(value)`)  and assign the value to `trackBar1.Value`  It could be you already have the value and are trying to assign a `string` to an `int` `trackBar1.Value = row.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString();` will never work  `trackBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["priority"].Value);` might

Comment: @Fred put this comment on answer ,than I can match as answered! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657137/datagridview-full-row-selection-but-get-single-cell-value) will show you the base of what you want but....

It could be you already have the value and are trying to assign a `string` to an `int` `trackBar1.Value = row.Cells["priority"].Value.ToString();` will never work  `trackBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["priority"].Value);` might