# How can I only code this once and replicate c#

Tags: c#, class

I am new to C# and classes. I was testing on making a datagridview where the user can right click and a contextmenustrip pops. Now my question is the following.

I made my code to add the text to the textbox and increase the textbox if it is not empty.[With help from this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657137/datagridview-full-row-selection-but-get-single-cell-value)

```
private void TsmItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int rowindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int columnindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        double resultText;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox.Text))
        {
            Textbox.Text = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            string selectedCell;
            selectedCell = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
            ResultText = Convert.ToDouble(Textbox.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(selectedCell);
            Textbox.Text = Convert.ToString(ResultText);
        }
}
```

Is there a way to only have this code only 1 time and call it every time I need it. So that I only have to change the textboxes.Text? Otherwise I need to copy and paste this code more than 10 times.

**What I tried**

```
    private void TsmItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Textbox.Text = RightMouseClick(Textbox.Text);
    }


    private void RightMouseClick(string txtResult)
    {
        int rowindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int columnindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtResult))
        {
            txtResult = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            string selectedCell;
            double resultText;
            selectedCell = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
            resultaat = Convert.ToDouble(txtResult) + Convert.ToDouble(selectedCell);
            txtResult = Convert.ToString(resultText);
        }
    }
```

**Fix**

```
        private string RightMouseClick(TextBox txtResult)
    {
        int rowindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int columnindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtResult.Text))
        {
            return txtResult.Text = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            string selectedCell;
            double resultaat;
            selectedCell = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
            resultaat = Convert.ToDouble(txtResult.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(selectedCell);
            return txtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(resultaat);
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you want to create reusable method then you only use common code and add *specific* parts via parameters. What are specific parts in your method? You are passing `Text`, how about passing a complete `TextBox` control?

Comment: You can map  clicks for all the textboxes to same event handler. In your designer you should add this.textBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.RightClick); this.textBox2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.RightClick); and so on. Then in your event handler sender will be the textbox and EventArgs will contain the mouse arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the textbox as a parameter

```
    private void RightMouseClick(TextBox txtBox)
    {
        int rowindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        int columnindex = dgvResults.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtResult))
        {
            txtBox.Text = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            string selectedCell;
            double resultText;
            selectedCell = dgvResults.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value.ToString();
            resultaat = Convert.ToDouble(txtBox.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(selectedCell);
            txtBox.Text = Convert.ToString(resultText);
        }
    }
```

You should ensure that you also checking to make sure that the textbox isn't NULL

Comment: Thank you for this reply. I modified some parts so that It's works, Now I can call it on every rightclick action.