# Change cell style of a DataGridView while the user is editing and typing in cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, keypress

I need to change the back color of a `DataGridView` cell based on certain conditions, as the user is editing the cell. Right now I can only change the `BackColor` after the cell loses focus.

Specifically, while the user is typing in a cell, I need to check the `DataTable` that the `DataGridView` is bound to to compare what the user is typing to what value is in the DataTable in the corresponding cell. If it's different, I need to change the `BackColor` to Yellow. And if the user changes the value in the cell back to the original value in the DataTable, I need to remove the color.

I tried messing around with the `KeyPress` event, but I can't figure out how to get the specific row/column index of the cell being edited so I can correctly check it's value against the corresponding `DataTable`'s row/column index value.

Comment: I think you want to use the [CurrentCell.RowIndex and .ColumnIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12864283/3585500).

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy, You need to handle a few things:

- The cell editing control is different from the cell, so when edit is beginning, find the editing control and set the initial color for that by comparing the text with the datasource value.
- When the editing controls is going to show, handle it's `TextChanged` event and in the `TextChanged` event handler, compare the text with the datasource value and colorize textbox based on that.
- When you finish editing, the value will not push to data source, until after you leave the record or call end edit explicitly, so when edit is ending, push value to the data source.
- Handle cell painting and colorize the cell.
- Use a different color for new rows (if you like). They are different from modified rows, they don't have an original version.
- Since we have handled cell painting, if the values in data source change, the cell will be repainted.

Here is the screen capture:

[image]

Here is a working example:

```
public DataTable GetProducts()
{
    var products = new DataTable();
    products.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    products.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    products.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(int));
    products.Rows.Add(1, "Product 1", 100);
    products.Rows.Add(2, "Product 2", 200);
    products.AcceptChanges();
    return products;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = GetProducts();
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
    dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;
    dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit;
    dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += dataGridView1_CellEndEdit;
}
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;
    var drv = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
    if (drv != null)
    {
        drv.EndEdit();
    }
}
private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;
    BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        var textBox = dataGridView1.EditingControl as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            SetEditingControlColor(textBox);
        }
    }));
}
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
        return;
    var drv = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
    if (drv != null && drv.Row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original))
    {
        var column = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
        if (drv.Row[column, DataRowVersion.Current]
            .Equals(drv.Row[column, DataRowVersion.Original]))
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        return;
    }
    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
}
void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = e.Control as DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.TextChanged -= textbox_TextChanged;
        textBox.TextChanged += textbox_TextChanged;
    }
}
private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)sender;
    SetEditingControlColor(textBox);
}
void SetEditingControlColor(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl textBox)
{
    var dgv = textBox.EditingControlDataGridView;
    var drv = dgv.CurrentCell.OwningRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
    if (drv != null && drv.Row.HasVersion(DataRowVersion.Original))
    {
        var column = dgv.Columns[dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].DataPropertyName;
        var value = drv.Row[column, DataRowVersion.Original];
        if (textBox.Text.Equals($"{value}"))
        {
            textBox.BackColor = Color.White;
            textBox.Parent.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            textBox.Parent.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        }
        return;
    }
    textBox.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
    textBox.Parent.BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
}
```

Comment: Marky, I wonder if you gave the solution a try? let me know if you find any issue or you find it useful :)