# Changing colors in WinForm DataGridView on keypress

Tags: c#, datagridview, keypress, backcolor

I have three columns in a `DataGridView` that are mutually dependent on each other. Lets label them column 1, 2, and 3 respectively. In this case column 1 must be less than column 2 and column 2 must be less than column three.

If I call the `SetValidBandByRow()` function below while in the `sysIdentGV_CellValueChanged` the cell colors are the expected Light Pink to indicate that there is an error in one of the three cells and needs to be addressed. However when `SetValidBandByRow(...)` is called from a `KeyPress` event it registers that a new value violates the condition but the cell that is being edited does not retain the cell colors set in `SetValidBandByRow(...)`. In an attempt to fix this I have caught that the `KeyPress` by setting the textbox backcolor to Light pink however I get a white boarder see the "while editing" image below.

```cs
private void sysIdentGV_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    /*some other validation and building of the rltu object here */

    if(!SetValidBandByRow(rltu))
    {
        /*building error msg and displaying error*/
    }
    return;
}

private bool SetValidBandByRow(Tuple<int,double,double,double> rowLowerTransUpper)
{
    bool wasValid = true;

    if (rowLowerTransUpper.Item1 < 0 || rowLowerTransUpper.Item1 >= GV.RowCount)
        return wasValid;

    Color color = Color.White;
    if (!(rowLowerTransUpper.Item2 <= rowLowerTransUpper.Item3 && rowLowerTransUpper.Item3 <= rowLowerTransUpper.Item4))
    {
        color = Color.LightPink;
        wasValid = false;
    }

    GV.Rows[row].Cells[(int)GVEnum.lowerCutoff].Style.BackColor = color;
    GV.Rows[row].Cells[(int)GVEnum.TransFreq].Style.BackColor = color;
    GV.Rows[row].Cells[(int)GVEnum.upperCutoff].Style.BackColor = color;

    return wasValid;
}
```

Setting `tb.backcolor` on `GV_Keypress` (Cell is still in focus):

[image: while editing]

Not setting `tb.backcolor` on `GV_Keypress` (Cell is still in focus):

[image: while editing]

after setting GV.Rows[row].`Cells`[(int)GVEnum.lowerCutoff].Style.BackColor
and SelectionBackColor on `GV_CellValueChanged`:

[image: after defocusing from textbox]

I am hoping to either remove the white space around the "while editing" image or find another approach that seems like less of a workaround.

This is some things that I have tried to set the textbox back color but nothing seems to be working as I would expect:

```cs
private void GV_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

/*some other validation and building of the rltu object here */

//the result of the section below can be seen in image 1 "Setting 
//active textbox back color" with out this section I get image two.

TextBox tb = (TextBox)GV.EditingControl;
if (!SetValidBandByRow(rltu))
{
    tb.Margin = new Padding(0);
    GV.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
    GV.CurrentCell.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightPink;
    tb.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
}
else
    tb.BackColor = Color.White;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I am not following what you are trying to do. `IF` at least ONE (1) of the values in at least One(1) of the three (3) cells is greater than the next cell, `THEN` color just that cell or the whole row? In addition “where” is the “KeyPressed” code? In the last snippet of code I can see a `TextBox` being created from the grids `EditingControl`, but where is the “KeyPressed” code. In other words, none of the posted code is going to get executed if multiple keys are pressed while the cell is in edit mode.

Comment: I am guessing that… is what you want… is that when the user starts typing into one of the cells, that you want the cell to be colored pink as soon as the number the user typed is greater than the next cell? In other words, “when” do you want the cell(s) to be colored? When the user “types” or when the user “leaves” the cell. Can you clarify any of this?

Comment: I suggest you peruse the SO [tour] section as it shows how SO works. The [ask] section may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful. Creating a full [mre] is one way to get answers quickly.

Comment: @JohnG yes sorry I should have provided more context. Ideally the cell would change color while the user is "typing". so keypress, determine if the new string would violate the condition and the entire cell without a boarder would be light pink and would remain that way once defocused. I will edit my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking to do something similar. The question was answered in another stack over flow question that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276563/change-cell-style-of-a-datagridview-while-the-user-is-editing-and-typing-in-cell)