# How to copy just parts of a DataGridView to Clipboard?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, clipboard

It is a very silly question, but I couldn't find a solution on my own nor with the Internet.

I have a `DataGridView copy to clipboard` button which works, however the first column and the last row should ***not*** be copied.

```
Private Sub btnExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click
    dgv.SelectAll()
    Dim cb As DataObject = dgv.GetClipboardContent()
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(cb, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521152/datagridview-copy-complete-to-clipboard/10525686) gives you something. Also check [DataGridView.SelectedRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=netframework-4.8) and [DataGridView.SelectedCells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells?view=netframework-4.8) properties.

Comment: @JQSOFT the first link is close to my question, but that's c# and some of the functionalities from there can't be "translated" to vb.
The second and third link don't match my question.